# Google Cloud Platform REST API: Acquiring Access Token and API Key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication, rest

I wish to use the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) REST API locally, starting with the `apps.services.versions.instances.list` method.

The route works when I use "Try this API" [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list), but how would I use this method locally with `curl`?

```sh
"https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/$APPSID/services/$SERVICESID/versions/$VERSIONSID/instances?key=$YOUR_API_KEY" \
--compressed \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

#=>

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

How do I access `$YOUR_API_KEY` and `$YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`?  I have been unable to find either in the official GCP docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You no longer need an API key. It's a legacy feature of Google APIs, provide only an access token is enough.

In command line you can do this

```
 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://....
```

All the Google Cloud APIs are compliant with access token authentication. Few are still compliant with API keys.

**About APIKeys API**

This API has been published in beta and now closed. At least the documentation part. I don't know if this API is stable or subject to change. You can create an API key per API like this (very similar to Bartosz Pelikan answer)

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
   -X POST https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/apiKeys
```

*As you can see, I reuse the access token authentication mode*

Comment: If you are `POST`ing JSON to an API then it's important to specify `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` otherwise CURL infers application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the response status will likely be `INVALID_ARGUMENT`

Answer (score 8):

The fastest way is use Cloud Shell:

1. List projects to get project id

   ```
   gcloud projects list

   # save you project id
   PROJECT_ID="YOURS_PROJECT_ID"
   ```
2. Get ACCESS_TOKEN

   ```
   ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
   ```
3. Get API_KEY

   ```
   API_KEY=$(curl -X POST https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/apiKeys?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN | jq -r ".currentKey")
   ```
4. Print API_KEY and ACCESS_TOKEN

   ```
   echo $ACCESS_TOKEN
   echo $API_KEY
   ```

To run above commands on local machine first you need authenticate using command `gcloud auth login` and follow instructions.

Alternatively api key could be readed or created from console go to `Navigation Menu` ->  `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials` and next click on `CREATE CREDENTIALS` -> `API Key`.

---

By reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list?apix=true) (clicking on question mark next to `Credentials`) we can read:

- `[YOUR_API_KEY]` - "Include an API Key to identify your project, used to verify enablement and track request quotas."
- `[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]` - "Include an access (bearer) token to identify the user which completed the OAuth flow with your Client ID."

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! But, I am still having issues. In Cloud Shell, I am able to get my access token with the command, but for API_KEY, I get 'null'.  So, instead I tried the other approach creating an API key from console. So, now I got both an API key and my access token. But when I run the curl command, I get "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects" with 400 status code. I for sure created the API key in the same project as Cloud Shell. Do you have any idea What I might be doing wrong thats causing this?? Thank you!

Comment: Are you tried to use `gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID` before use command with $PROJECT_ID the same that the services are you use?

Comment: The endpoint suggested in this answer isn't public. I was having trouble getting it to work and I reached out to GCP support. They said "It appears the API keys API is not available to the public."

Comment: does not work for v2 e.g. https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v2

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are using an API that isn't publicly available (I reached out to GCP support an confirmed.

I recommend using the CLI tool like so:

`gcloud app instances list --service core-api --project my-project-name`

docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/list

You'll have to a [gcloud auth](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth) first and probably set your project.